# Create multiple numpy arrays of same size at once

Tags: python, numpy

It's a silly question, but a question nontheless. Whenever I need to create several numpy arrays of same size I end up doing

```
size = 100
time = np.zeros(size)
amplitude = np.zeros(size)
frequency = np.zeros(size)
```

or in some cases I use `time.copy()`. Is there a way to so something like the following?

```
size = 100
time, amplitude, frecuency = make_many(np.zeros(size))
```

Comment: Are you hoping to save time or typing?

Comment: Typing. The answer linked as a duplication is exacly what I was looking for. I just couldn't find it with the way I worded my searches.